# Java generics, method base() is undefined for the type T

Tags: java, generics, types, undefined

I am trying to understand generics in java, and trying this simple example, but can't make it work; it comes back with error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>           The method base() is undefined for the type T
>           at javaTest.Main.testShape(Main.java:21)
>           at javaTest.Main.main(Main.java:25)

Below is the code

```
class Shape{
    int id=1;
    void base(){
        System.out.println("Shape.base()");
    }
}

// unrelated class, but same func name
class OtherShape{
    float id=1.1f;
    void base(){
        System.out.println("OtherShape.base()");
    }
}

public class Main {

    static <T>void testShape(T shape){
        shape.base();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        testShape(new Shape() );
        testShape(new OtherShape());        
    }
}
```

any idea on how I can make it work ?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf: the first line in code same above:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method base() is undefined for the type T
    at javaTest.Main.testShape(Main.java:21)
    at javaTest.Main.main(Main.java:25)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Java generics are compiled without outside context, therefore the code must be valid without knowing how at the end it will be called.

Declaring something `<T>` means that you can pass anything that is object, so `T var` means that at the compile time `var` is supposed to be just `java.lang.Object`. Therefore `var.base()` doesn't make sense as `java.lang.Object` doesn't provide method called `base()`.

You can tell that `T` is at least `Shape` for example by declaring `<T extends Shape>`, then you can pass anything which inherits from `Shape`. However, your second example will still not work as `OtherShape` doesn't inherit from `Shape`, i.e. it doesn't satisfy condition `<T extends Shape>`.

To fix it completely it should look like this:

```
class Shape{
    int id=1;
    void base(){
        System.out.println("Shape.base()");
    }
}

// unrelated class, but same func name
class OtherShape extends Shape{
    float id=1.1f;
    @Override
    void base(){
        System.out.println("OtherShape.base()");
    }
}

public class Main {

    static <T extends Shape> void testShape(T shape){
        shape.base();
    }
    ...
}
```

One step forward would be to make `Shape` an interface and rather create each shape class (`TriangleShape`, `OtherShape`, ...) implementing that interface.

Note anyway that in your example you don't really require generics, they are rather useful if you need to refer to the same type later, like for example returning it back from the method:

```
    static <T extends Shape> T testShape(T shape){
        shape.base();
        return shape;
    }
```

In the example above you can still assign the result of such method into the same type as you passed in the parameter because parameter type and return type are the same (`T`).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are getting that issue because you are not casting T to any object type. Try doing it like this.

```
class Shape{
    int id=1;
    void base(){
        System.out.println("Shape.base()");
    }
}

// unrelated class, but same func name
class OtherShape extends Shape{
    float id=1.1f;
    void base(){
        System.out.println("OtherShape.base()");
    }
}

public class Test {

    static void testShape(Shape shape){
        shape.base();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        testShape(new Shape() );
        testShape(new OtherShape());        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual error message you're getting is:

```
The method base() is undefined for the type T
```

And that is exactly your problem: your method is designed to operate on a type `T` and you have said that `T` can be *literally any object type*. Since `T` could be `String`, or `Number`, or some other random object that somebody else created, you can't assume it will have any particular methods on the object. Therefore, the method `base()` is **undefined** for the type `T`, since `T` is not necessarily a type that has a `base()` method. Does that make sense?

If what you want to is to operate on *any type that has a `base()` method*, that is a thing called [*structural typing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) which **Java unfortunately does not support**. (Java's type system is [nominative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) instead.)

The next best thing is to define an interface to hold your `base()` method, and implement that interface in both your classes:

```
interface ShapeInterface {
  void base();
}

class Shape implements ShapeInterface {
  ...
}

class OtherShape implements ShapeInterface {
  ...
}
```

But then you no longer need *parametric polymorphism* (that is, *generics*), since you can use plain old [*subtype polymorphism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) instead: since `Shape` and `OtherShape` both support an *is-a* relationship with `ShapeInterface`, your `testShape` method can just accept a `ShapeInterface` and interact with it directly:

```
static void testShape(ShapeInterface shape) {
  shape.base();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it only if you implement the same interface for the classes.

```
interface S {
    void base();
}

static void testShape(S shape){
    shape.base();
}
```